# Como hacer un validación de un login en php?

Tags: php, mysql, login, validación, session

Soy muy nueva en esto, pero necesito hacer un proyecto que requiere de la validación de un login, y la verdad mi código es muy pobre. Espero que alguien me pueda recomendar algun tutorial (ya he visto muchos por cierto), o algo para mejorar mi código. He hecho muchos códigos, pero aquí les dejo el más reciente. Gracias

NOTA: el documento es el usuario en este código.

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

$usuario = $_POST["documento"];
$clave = $_POST["contrasena"];

$consulta = " SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE documento = '$usuario' and  contrasena = '$clave' " ;

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion , $consulta) ;
$datos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if($datos > 0){
    header("location:interfaz.php");
}else{
    echo "Datos incorrectos";
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
include "desconexion.php";
```

Comment: agrega el código para darnos una idea de lo que tienes, y a partir de eso darte recomendaciones.

Comment: Listo! Ya anadi el codigo

Comment: Te da algun error?

Comment: Saludos. Mira referente a sesiones ( https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php ); todo sistema lo que requiere es tener elementos bien conocidos mediante los cuales identifique si se ha iniciado sesión con datos válidos. Cuando este/estos existan permitir acceso a las página que requieren o sino direccionar al visitante a la pantalla de logeo para generar estos elementos (generalmente tu como desarrollador(a) defines cuales son asi como su tratamiento y uso.

Answer (score 0):

Recomiendo,

1. Validar que los valores de user y password no estén nulos, en la documentación de PHP https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php
2. En la consulta, cambiar ésta parte SELECT * por esta SELECT COUNT(*) , es más costoso traerse todas las columnas, el COUNT retornará el número de filas de la consulta, que en e ste caso debería ser 0 ó 1
3. Puede reemplazar éste código,  `$datos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);` por $datos = `mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)[0];` , ésto devolverá el valor numérico de la consulta el cuál será 0 ó 1.

Eso es, hay muchas formas de hacer conexiones, pero a la que presenta se le podrían hacer esos ajustes.